# Dynamically Select DataFrames out of txt file containing multiple dataframes (Articial Index required to slice data based on index)

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, data-cleaning, feature-selection

I'm new to Python but gathered a data challenge. I hope I can find help for this challenge here.

**I need to clean and harmonize a txt-log-file containing multiple DataFrames with dynamical length.** The dataframes are stored below each other. Actually I would need kind of an artifical index to filter for the contents of one dataframe in order to clean and format the dataframe.

[image: Original Data Frame vs. Desired DataFrame]

**Problem:** I need to filter the log-file to extract the single KPI from each frame. Therefore I need to preprocess and clean the Hex-numbers and scientific writing of some numbers. Can you help me to create a new column with an index containing just the table name (see right DataFrame and column index). The name of the indexes are just in two columns and specific rows. Currently I don't know how to add them correctly as table identification.

Please help me.

Best regards

CuriousDataScientist

```py
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Table   COST                    
REAL    REAL    REAL    REAL            
IDnxska52P  154564564   421564564   364564564   456456  35635   
Table   Instruments 421564564   364564564   456456  53536   
STRING  REAL    REAL    REAL    REAL    REAL    REAL
IDnxska52P  3,5 50  3,5 50  3,5 50
IDnxska53P  6,5 7,5 6,5 7,5 6,5 7,5
IDnxska54P  3,5 50  3,5 50  3,5 50
IDnxska55P  6,5 7,5 6,5 7,5 6,5 7,5
IDnxska56P  3,5 50  6,5 7,5 7,5 7,5
Table   PC  50  6,5 7,5 7,5 7,5
STRING  REAL    REAL    REAL    REAL    REAL    REAL
HTZ30    0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+00
HTZ31    0.000000000000000E+01   0.000000000000000E+01   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+01   0.000000000000000E+01   0.000000000000000E+01
HTZ30    0.000000000000000E+02   0.000000000000000E+02   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+02   0.000000000000000E+02   0.000000000000000E+02
HTZ31    0.000000000000000E+03   0.000000000000000E+03   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+03   0.000000000000000E+03   0.000000000000000E+03
HTZ32    0.000000000000000E+04   0.000000000000000E+04   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+04   0.000000000000000E+04   0.000000000000000E+04
HTZ33    0.000000000000000E+05   0.000000000000000E+05   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+05   0.000000000000000E+05   0.000000000000000E+05
HTZ34    0.000000000000000E+06   0.000000000000000E+06   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+06   0.000000000000000E+06   0.000000000000000E+06
HTZ35    0.000000000000000E+07   0.000000000000000E+07   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+07   0.000000000000000E+07   0.000000000000000E+07
HTZ36    0.000000000000000E+08   0.000000000000000E+08   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+08   0.000000000000000E+08   0.000000000000000E+08
HTZ37    0.000000000000000E+09   0.000000000000000E+09   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+09   0.000000000000000E+09   0.000000000000000E+09
HTZ38    0.000000000000000E+10   0.000000000000000E+10   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+10   0.000000000000000E+10   0.000000000000000E+10
HTZ39    0.000000000000000E+11   0.000000000000000E+11   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+11   0.000000000000000E+11   0.000000000000000E+11
HTZ40    0.000000000000000E+12   0.000000000000000E+12   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+12   0.000000000000000E+12   0.000000000000000E+12
HTZ41    0.000000000000000E+13   0.000000000000000E+13   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+13   0.000000000000000E+13   0.000000000000000E+13
HTZ42    0.000000000000000E+14   0.000000000000000E+14   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+14   0.000000000000000E+14   0.000000000000000E+14
HTZ43    0.000000000000000E+15   0.000000000000000E+15   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+15   0.000000000000000E+15   0.000000000000000E+15
HTZ44    0.000000000000000E+16   0.000000000000000E+16   0.000000000000000E+00   0.000000000000000E+16   0.000000000000000E+16   0.000000000000000E+16
```

Comment: What does the data actually look like in the file?

Comment: Dear AMC - the data and the txt-logfile has the same format as above. The numbers are unconverted floats in scientific notatation so e.g. instead of the float 0,3 it's 00000+3E. The rest of the file is identical with the example shown above.

Comment: That looks like it Excel, which makes it more difficult to understand what is really going on. In any case, we're going to need some sample input and output.

Comment: I added the data snippet. Please feel free to copy the data into a txt file.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How is the data organized? How can you tell where one DF ends and another begins, etc. ?

Comment: This us exactly My problem. I can‘t tell except the data snippet provided

Comment: Ah, that makes things quite tough. Where does this data come from, is there any way to sidestep this problem entirely?

Comment: Dear AMC - I did in manually meanwhile via extracting 30 Excel Tables and unifying them via VBA. It's an SAP Infoquery.

Comment: Can something be changed closer to the source, then?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm only user - I can not access the settings of the info cube. But thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not familiar with the system, how do you interact with it and receive the data? Does it produce that "broken" file directly?